# Woocommerce replace add to cart button with custom button/link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to replace the Add to Cart button (only on certain categories) with a custom button for "Text a Dealer." The "Text a Dealer" button will trigger a gravity form in a lightbox which allows the user to submit a text message over the Twilio SMS service.

Here is a [screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/qysuRaeul)

I think I know how to link the button to a form in a lightbox but I do not know how to replace the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button' );
function replace_default_button(){
    return '<button>Text a Dealer</button>';
}
```

You can replace button code with your desired code.
This will replace the default button code with your custom code.

You also want this customization to be applicable only on certain categories. This can be achieved by addition of some more code. See below.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button' );
function replace_default_button(){
    //list category slugs where button needs to be changed
    $selected_cats = array('cat-one-slug', 'cat-two-slug', 'cat-three-slug');
    //get current category object
    $current_cat = get_queried_object();
    //get category slug from category object
    $current_cat_slug = $current_cat->slug;
    //check if current category slug is in the selected category list
    if( in_array($current_cat_slug, $selected_cats) ){
        //replace default button code with custom code
        return '<button>Text a Dealer</button>';
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array();
    if ( $product ) {
        $defaults = array(
            'quantity'   => 1,
            'class'      => implode(
                ' ',
                array_filter(
                    array(
                        'button add-to-cart-loop',
                        'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                        $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                        $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $args = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults ), $product );

        $price = $product->get_price();
        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
            sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" data-product_price_'.esc_attr( $product->get_id() ).'="'. $price .'" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s"><span>%s</span></a>',
                esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['quantity'] ) ? $args['quantity'] : 1 ),
                esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
                esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button' ),
                esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
            ),
        $product );
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.